# $http.get() function can't identify local server's json structured template | AngularJs | Django

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, json, django

I'm using angularjs with Django.
Here is my angularjs script:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.name = 'sh';
    $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/ls/').then(function(response){
        $scope.code = response.status;
        $scope.text = response.statusText; 
        $scope.data = response.data;
    },function(){
        $scope.message = 'not found!';
    });
});
```

And here's my http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/ls/ page's result:

```
{'record':[{'name':'your name','post':'dp'},{'name':'sdfsdfyour name','post':'sdfsfsfdp'},{'name':'your namefdsfsd','post':'dpsfdfsdf'},{'name':'your namesdfsdfs','post':'dpfsfdsfs'}]}
```

But `$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/ls')` function showing me it's  `$scope.message`'s data as result. And you know that this result will be only shown while $http.get() will be failed to find the specific page. Have any suggestion/solution, please?

Comment: Have you made sure your API is returning a HTTP status code of say 200?

Comment: No. But **http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/ls** url is working into browser and gives me a page like I've listed above.

Comment: Regardless of whether you see it in the browser, you'll have to ensure that a successful HTTP status code and valid JSON is provided else you'll be thrown into the `catch` handler. You can check the status code in developer tools in any browser.

Comment: Ok. I'm trying'. Thanks for suggest.